# Chromecast Status Code 2001

Tags: chromecast

I have an application thats send around 150+ KB to the Chromecast Dongle using the sample HelloText app from GitHub, however on the onReceive callback, I receive a `Unknown Status Code 2001`.

What does this status code imply since it's not documented anywhere in the official SDK documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you breaking your data into smaller pieces and send or you are trying to send everything in one shot? I believe there is a limit of 64K per message (I might be wrong on the exact number though, but it is < 150K). 2001 error code means it is an invalid requests.

Comment: How do you know 2001 is an 'invalid request'? I'm looking for the list of status codes.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes.html

Comment: How could we be sure about the max size of the message?

Comment: Consider that being 64K